# live-server gives "Change detected" but chrome console doesn't, how do I make my change auto loaded?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to have [live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) auto reload the code once I save my change.

I've installed live-server globally and created a folder `test` and put 3 files in there

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch index.html main.js .live-server.json
live-server
```

Here's the contents of **index.html**

```
<script src='main.js'></script>
```

Here's the contents of **main.js**

```
console.log('hi');
```

and I got 'hi' in my chrome `dev` console.

When I changed the code, I got

> Change detected /Users/ubuntu/dev/test/main.js

However, my chrome dev console didn't yield that change. I have to refresh the page manually. How do I make my change auto loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly update your `browser` and `live-server` package!
Try to re-run your `live-server` without `.live-server.json` (*remove it !*) file because as we can read in docs:

> If a file ~/.live-server.json exists it will be loaded and used as
> default options for live-server on the command line. See "**Usage from
> node**" for option names.

You need to add to your `index.html` **boilerplate** ! Now it should works like a charm! ;-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also try run `live-server` with different `port` like so:

```
live-server --port=5000
```